# What is the 'opposite' of ekphrasis?

Tags: antonyms, poetry

Given that ekphrasis means, according to the Poetry Foundation, "an ekphrastic poem is a vivid description of a scene or, more commonly, a work of art", is there a term to describe the 'opposite' where a visual artist depicts a work of verbal art?

Comment: It specifically refers to a "verbal representation of a visual representation" ( A Sence of the Whole, reading Gary Snyders Mountains and Rivers Without End by Mark Gonnerman) . I am also curious of its antonym.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Greek word **έκφραση** means *expression* ([see here](http://www.wordreference.com/gren/%CE%AD%CE%BA%CF%86%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%B7) , the antonym would be *impression*.

However, that is not the kind of antonym you're looking for, it seems.

The trick lies in the expression *ekphrastic poem*, which, freely translated, would be a poem that *expresses* (a scene or a work of art).

You do not want a *poem* that does the opposite, but rather a *painting* that does a similar thing, which could be called an *ekphrastic* painting.

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't have the same fine resonance as "ekphrasis" but I think "illustration" as in The Illustrated Shakespeare.  There are innumerable fine art paintings, drawings, etchings, and so on illustrating textual passages from Shakespeare, Dante, the Bible, Greco-Roman myths and legends, and outside of fine art there are even more innumerable examples.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a term to describe the 'opposite' where a visual artist depicts a work of verbal art?

**Depiction**:

OED:

> Etymology: < Latin dēpictiōn-em, noun of action < dēpingĕre : see depict v<sup>1</sup>.
>
> **The action of depicting; painted representation, picture; graphic description.**

<sup>1</sup>**depict, v.**

> Etymology: < Latin dēpict-, participial stem of Latin dēpingĕre to represent by painting, portray, depict, < de- prefix 1c + pingĕre to paint: compare depaint v. and depict adj.
>
> **1.a.** transitive. *To draw, figure, or represent in colours; to paint; also, in wider sense, to portray, delineate, figure anyhow.*